# Selecting all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

This should be really simple but I'm a javascript/jQuery rookie, so here we go:

With the following code I can select a certain element

```
var user = $(".ui-selected .user-name").html();
```

But if there are multiple elements with the above classes, only the first value gets selected. What I would like to accomplish is a variable with all the elements seperated by a , like: user1,user2,user3 ... etc. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get an array of values, then [`.join()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) them to a string, like this:

```
var usersString = $(".ui-selected .user-name").map(function() {
                    return $(this).html(); //or this.innerHTML
                  }).get().join(',');
```

Edit: [here's a demo, you can tweak the join, etc if needed](http://jsfiddle.net/ybnxS/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use .each() to go through each one:

```
$(".ui-selected .user-name").each( function(){
    var user = $( this ).html();
    // do stuff
} )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var myElements = "";
$(".ui-selected .user-name").each( function(){
   myElements += $(this).html() + ",";
} )
```

Comment: You'll end up with a dangling comma at the end that you'll need to truncate. Better (in my opinion) to push items into an array, and `.join(',')`, or have jQuery build the array with `.map()`.